# Good sample of asynchronous comment system for ASP.NET MVC, JSON and JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, comments

Can anyone jot down a complete sample for creating an asynchronous comment mechanism [like this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/asynchronous-comments-with-jquery-and-json/), but focusing on ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the Encouraged Commentary system

Explained:
http://donttrustthisguy.com/2009/01/04/encouraged-commentary/

Code:
http://github.com/jimjeffers/encouraged-commentary